# Regarding Parent Page updation in case of same page used multiple time

Tags: dotnetnuke

I am novice programmer to Dot net nuke.

Login as Admin:

1) I add a page in Home -- Department. Department page have on Text/HTML module which have some lines ie (Welcome to DNN.) 
2) Now click on Home page then add this page (Control Panel --> Add existing module) to Home Page. 
3) Now as we can modifying data of Department Page, either from Home page or from Home--> Department page, which will be reflecting on both pages. 
4) We want that modify option (Edit Text) must be available with Home --> Department page only. There must not be no editing option at Home page to edit Department page.

How to do that?

I am using Sql Server 2008/DotNetNuke_Community_04.09.05_Source / ISS V5.1/ VS2008.

Comment: You should not just ask for code.

Answer (score 0):

This isn't really possible in DNN, if you have the ability to EDIT a page, then you have the ability to edit any MODULE on that page, including modules that are copied from other pages.

You could remove the ability for the person to EDIT the homepage, and then only give them the ability to edit certain MODULES on the homepage instead.

FYI DotNetNuke is spelled without any spaces, and is actually now just DNN or DNNPlatform